# How to use existing NSManaged object model to add data from different places

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Here is how i am showing data to the `CoreData` which is i am getting from server through `JSON` in dictionary `NSDictionary` *dict.

```
  NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error1];
                    NSLog(@"results:%@",results);

                    NSManagedObject *updateDevice=[results lastObject];

                    if([results count] > 0){
                        //if(1){
                        NSLog(@"updateeeee");
                        //continue;
         [updateDevice setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"clip_image_path"]] forKey:@"clip_image_path"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"clip_name"] forKey:@"clip_name"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"page_categorisation"] forKey:@"page_categorisation"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"modifieddate"] forKey:@"modifieddate"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[commonvideo stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"path"] ]]forKey:@"clip_path"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"description"] forKey:@"descriptions"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"created_by"] forKey:@"created_by"];
         [updateDevice setValue:[dict objectForKey:@"state"]  forKey:@"state"];
```

And following is my code to add the clip information to server which is on different view. Here all i want to do is that i want to store the data from the `textFields` to the above attributes which are in Entity "ClipTable" so i am having problem how to update the existing managed object. This `afnetworking` i call when submit button is clicked after which it stores the information to the server through API. Now i want to update the `CoreData` model after the clip upload. Hard time fixing it, any help is appreciated.

```
  -(void)afnetworking{

NSString *user_id=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"userID"];

NSString *urlString =K_ServerAPI;
NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request2 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

[request2 addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Your uploading file.
NSMutableData *bodyData = [NSMutableData data];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  // [bodyData appendData:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userID"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[user_id dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"task\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"webapi.insertClip" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

below is the nameCliptxt.text i have to update the "clip_name" in the above CoreData
model by the information which is in the textField like wise i have to do for all the things below

```
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"clip_name\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[nameCliptxt.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[detailtxtView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"page_categorisation\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[pageIdArray objectAtIndex:[pageCategoryArray indexOfObject:pagecategoryTxtFild.text]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_category\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[[videoIdarray objectAtIndex:[arrayofVideoCategory indexOfObject:videoTextFiled.text]]  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_tag\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[video_Tag.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:bodyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Request body %@",strData);

NSString *videoUrl=[selectedVideoURL path];
if(videoUrl){
    NSString *videoName = [[videoUrl lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSData *videoData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:selectedVideoURL];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString *tmpfileinfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video_clip\"; filename=\"%@.mp4\"\r\n",videoName];
    [bodyData appendData:[tmpfileinfo dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Can you specify what you want to have happen and what you're seeing that's different from that?

Comment: I guess you want to update data of NSManagedObject that you have saved earlier through JSON response. If I got you right, you will have to fetch the nsmanagedobject through fetch request with predicate to find given "id".After you get the object, you will set its values and again save context. Also a quick suggestion,  don't add a attribute name as "id", its a keyword you should "clipId" or some "xyzId" kind of attribute name.